# Interpret bash commands

Tags: bash, command

I checked some resources, but still hard to find a clue to interpret the codes.

`$ find . -iname "*.dwp" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.dwp}.html"' {} \;`
`$ find . -name ".DS_Store" -exec rm {} \;`

To be more specific, what's the difference between `-iname` and `-name`? And what does "-c" and "%" symbolize?

Can you interpret the two commands a bit for me?

Comment: [Findutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), (specifically [base name patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns)), [Bash invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html), [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Thanks! I"ll read that! :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one:

- `-iname "*.dwp"`, indicate to the `find` command to find files whose name matches the pattern `*.dwp`, ignore case, e.g.: `./a.dwp`
- `-exec expression {} \;` part, execute the command `bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.dwp}.html"' {}`. `{}` will be replaced by the path of each file. The expression is terminated by a semicolon. If there is a file `a.dwp` in the current directory, `bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.dwp}.html"' a.dwp` will  execute.

  ```
  bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.dwp}.html"' {}:
  ```

  - `-c` means read command from string, do not start an interactive shell.
  - `$0` is the argument of the command, `a.dwp` in this example.
  - `${0%\.dwp}.html` is string manipulation, `%` removes the shortest match from the end, so for `a.dwp`, remove `.dwp` from end to get the file name `a` without extension.

  So the command is  `mv a.dwp a.html`.

The second one is very simple if you understand first one.